# Excel 2010 Rorecast function

Tags: excel, formula, forecasting

Good morning

Strugling here with the Excel Forecasting function which is not something I have used before.  I spent a lot of time last week looking at it, and trawling many sites in search of wisdom.

I have been monitoring disk use on a number of PCs and servers to try to understand how the disk space is being used so we can project forward for the next 5-10 years.  I have data going back monthly from today - 2017-09-07 to 1994!  I don't need to go that far back, probably only the last 5 or 6 years.  Something like:

`Col.A   Col.B   Col.C   Col.D
Date    Free    Used    Capacity

2016-12 8680    313189  665589.4609
2017-01 13647   326836  665589.4609
2017-02 11599   338435  665589.4609
2017-03 19600   358035  665589.4609
2017-04 12864   370899  665589.4609
2017-05 68668   439567  665589.4609
2017-06 114265  553832  665589.4609
2017-07 64010   617842  665589.4609`

I have to get a forecast for the next few years to assess our forward storage capacity needs.  I think we'll hit 6TB in that time but need to prove it.  Its not a huge amount its very importand data and important for the manufacturing processes and I need to prove I need that capacity.

I keep getting #VALUEs or Divide by zero errors.

for example: If I use x as 1TB = 1099511627776
Known-y is the date
Known-x is the current trend data

it doesn't doesn't work however I do it.  I'm not sure if I'm using the formula the correct way.

Any help gratefully recieved.

Trying the Trend and Linest functions without any success.

Comment: According to Microsoft (https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/FORECAST-function-50ca49c9-7b40-4892-94e4-7ad38bbeda99) you get these error if one of the values are 0 or nonnumeric. Can you provide the formula that you are using in your file? Also, are there any empty rows or cells in your sheet?

Comment: No empty rows.  I have 242 data points to play with.  I'm not really sure what I'm supposed to be using for the known x or y - so assuming I'm graphing it - then x is the date column but that doesn't work, y is the Used column so just using the last few lines for this example,  have something like =FORECAST(D244,D233:D243,A233:A243) then I get a range of negaive numbers.  I've tried all permutations, not even sure if this is the right way to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you want to know when a 1 T disk is needed, enter the formula:

```
=FORECAST(1099511627776,range of date,range of data)
```

Important:range of date must be a date format. Propably in your sheet, for example '2016-12', is string format.

Comment: the date collumn is formatted yyyy-dd but I'll try puttiing a day in as well see if that works.